# Как "отделить" часть. Flexbox

Tags: html, css

Как сделать второй блок (справа) так же как и на макете. Код прикреплен.

Дело в том, что если я задам margin-top второму блоку он подвинет и nav вниз, кстати из-за второго блока у меня уже nav и поехал( Желательно на флексах сделать блок, но **главное без** js, bootstrap, position absolute.

---

Мой сайт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо чтобы было схоже с макетом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать второй блок напротив nav

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant:wght@300;400&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;700&family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgb(42, 61, 59);
    /* font-family: 'Cormorant', serif;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; */
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1110px;
}

.nav {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
    height: 75px;
}

.nav__item {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav__search {
    padding-left: 28px;
    background-image: url('../assets/header/search.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left
}

.info  {
    /* flex-basis: 430px; */
    flex-grow: .4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.info__title {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #43FFD2;
    text-align: end;
}

.info__text {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Lower Flower</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="nav">
            <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="assets/header/logo.png" alt="Логотип"></a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">Каталог</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">О нас</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">Контакты</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">FAQ</a>
            <a class="nav__item nav__search" href="#">Поиск</a>
         </nav>
         <div class="info">
            <div class="info__mail">
               <p class="info__title">zakaz@loverflower.by</p>
               <p class="info__text">Доставка 24/7 по договоренности с оператором</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="info__street">
               <p class="info__title">ул. Тимирязева 67</p>
               <p class="info__text">10:00 до 21:00 <br>без выходных</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не сильно менять текущие стили я бы делал следующим образом. Для вложенного в `info` на первом уровне устанавливал `margin-top`:

```
.info > [class^=info__] {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

А чтобы навигация не съезжала выровнял бы конкретно `nav` по старту:

```
.nav { 
  align-self: start;
}
```

Результат посмотреть можно тут:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant:wght@300;400&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;700&family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgb(42, 61, 59);
    /* font-family: 'Cormorant', serif;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; */
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1110px;
}

.nav {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
    height: 75px;
}

.nav__item {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav__search {
    padding-left: 28px;
    background-image: url('../assets/header/search.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left
}

.info  {
    /* flex-basis: 430px; */
    flex-grow: .4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.info__title {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #43FFD2;
    text-align: end;
}

.info__text {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: end;
}

.info > [class^=info__] {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav { 
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Lower Flower</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="nav">
            <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="assets/header/logo.png" alt="Логотип"></a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">Каталог</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">О нас</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">Контакты</a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="#">FAQ</a>
            <a class="nav__item nav__search" href="#">Поиск</a>
         </nav>
         <div class="info">
            <div class="info__mail">
               <p class="info__title">zakaz@loverflower.by</p>
               <p class="info__text">Доставка 24/7 по договоренности с оператором</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="info__street">
               <p class="info__title">ул. Тимирязева 67</p>
               <p class="info__text">10:00 до 21:00 <br>без выходных</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; <- убрать
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1110px;
    padding-top: 20px; <- добавить (или margin-top)
}
```